# javascript allow only tab, backspace and number keys

Tags: javascript, validation, onkeypress

In JavaScript code how to allow exception for tab and backspace.

On keypress event

```
onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event, this)"
```

> Code is

```
function isNumberKey(evt, el) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) return false;
        if (el.value.length > 2)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the keydown? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp

I read somewhere that the keypress is deprecated in JS.

Comment: Do you want allow only tab, backspace and numbers key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem,

I added exception in second condition

```
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    if (el.value.length >= 2 && charCode != 8)
        return false;

    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
      function isNumberKey(evt, el) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))) return false;
            if (el.value.length > 2)
                return false;

            return true;
        }
    </script>
<input type="text" id="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event, this)">
```